# How to print unicode character into string?

Tags: java, eclipse

Getting `invalid unicode` error with below code

Uniocde want to print: `unicode:0x16`

```java
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
char aa = "\u0x16";
pw.println(aa);
```

What's wrong happening here ?

Comment: It's \u0000. The x is unnecessary because the digits are assumed to be hex.

Comment: See [the Java Language Specification, section 3.3: Unicode Escapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3).

Comment: @VGR, thanks for sharing, Its cool read. But now am curious to know what's significance of unicodes ? Why they are rquired ? Are they used by any specfic hardware ?

Comment: Are you asking why it is necessary to specify four hex digits?  Because the Unicode specification contains codepoints for every language on earth, plus numerous standard symbol sets.  (And emojis, whether we like it or not.)  In fact, 2¹⁶ values was eventually found to be insufficient;  there are currently hundreds of thousands of codepoints in Unicode.

Comment: @VGR what do you mean by codePoints ?

Comment: For code points see [codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) - it is the numeric value for a character, [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) currently has 143,924 characters which are represented in Java using the [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding.

Comment: Note that the U+0016 code point is not a printable character. It actually the rather obscure [Synchronous Idle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_Idle) control character.

Comment: @greg-449, And from which encoding UniCodes are dervied from ? If we drill down any uniCode, what it will become? HEX ?

Comment: A `char` in Java is just a 16 bit integer. Unicode defines which character each of the possible values represents. The Java character '\u0016' is just the integer value 0x16 in hexadecimal or 22 in decimal.

Comment: @greg-449, Any book can you suggest to read all about encodings standards, covers from starting to now  ?

Comment: The Wikipedia [Character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) article looks like a reasonable start and has lots of references. This a complex subject with a lot of history! The first computer I used only had 6 bits per character (just 64 characters in total).

Comment: @greg-449, lucky you ...seen evolution in front of your eyes.! 

Answer (score 2):

`\u0x16` is not a valid unicode character reference. There should be 4 hexadecimal digits (numbers 0-9 letters a-f) after `\u` - the "x" is not valid.

If you meant to use the character U+0016, it's written as `\u0016`:

```
char aa = '\u0016';
```

The following is equivalent, but it uses an integer constant rather than a character constant.

```
char aa = 0x16;
```

Comment: Does x means 0 here ? Becasue while parsing XML i got this unicode (0x16), Secondly, I'm getting error while using "\u0016 "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to char", Any Idea how can I print that ?

Comment: The double quote " is used for String, the single quote ' is used for char. Make sure you use the right kind. Also, no, "x" does not mean zero, x is x. This is fundamental Java syntax I don't see how it is related to parsing XML